# Remote EJB server shutting down

Tags: ejb

In my application, I am using ejb. Server application is having ejb implementation. client application is calling server application and using ejb remotely. In my client application there is loop with 6000 iteration. EJB call needs to call 6000 times. But when calling 6000 times, server application is going down on 280th iteration. Kindly help me to fix this.